# creating user for postgresql on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I chose postgresql for my database for rails but i ran into an apparently common error where 'FATAL: role "app" does not exist' when i try to run rake db:create:all. I found two solutions but im not sure which one is the right one to use. One website says to

```
su -  
su - postgres
createuser -s Application
exit
exit
```

while the other says to

```
su - postgres
create role myapp with createdb login password 'password1'
```

what's the difference between the two? and which one should i use?

Comment: The second is invalid - you're mixing a shell command and a sql command. I would do the first, though I think it only works on debian systems. And I _wouldn't_ give it superuser capabilities.

Answer (score 19):

***You should use this for the development environment only***

Login in postgres console:

```
$> sudo -u postgres psql
```

create user with name `rails` and password:

```
=# create user rails with password 'password';
```

make user `rails` superuser:

```
=# alter role rails superuser createrole createdb replication;
```

create database `projectname` with owner `rails`:

```
=# create database projectname owner rails;
```

in `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: projectname
  pool:
  username: rails
  password: password
```

Comment: may I ask how about production env?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The only part that I didn't need was this one:
`=# create database projectname owner rails;`

Answer (score -1):

To create a user type this in your console

```
createuser
```

Enter the username and make it a superuser

Also you could add a password also by  adding pwprompt to createuser like this

```
createuser --pwprompt
```

Next you enter pgsql as postgres and create your database

sudo -u postgres psql postgres
create database db_name owner user_name;

Hope it helps

Refer this site for more details
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score -2):

The second option is invalid. That does not work.

---

**The first one:**

I don't recommend the first one and depending on your operating system some of the steps are unnecessary.

1. You become a *superuser* and make the shell a login shell (as if you would log in directly). I think it is risky and not necessary. Why not `su`ing directly to *postgre* user (that's just a matter of setup)?
2. You become *postgre* and make the shell a login shell
3. You create a superuser *Application* in PostgreSQL. So you have the privileges of a superuser for your application. I think that is risky too. Superuser for an application is very bad. Often you need `createdb`, `login` and `password` to get started and other privileges, if ever needed, can be added/revoked later.
4. You quit the *postgres* shell session.
5. You quit the *superuser* shell session

---

**The second one:**

That's not correct. You forget to execute `psql` command as second step. The second command would become the third. It would be like that.

1. You become *postgres* and make the shell a login shell
2. You log into postgres command shell by default with user *postgres*
3. You create a role `myapp` with options `createdb`, `login` and (usually by default encrypted) `password` with value *password1*.

---

The difference is that the first one grants superuser privileges to the *Application* role while the second grants only the listed permissions to the `myapp` role.
The second option is more secure. Among the two option opt for the seoconde one.

---

Note: In PostgreSQL a user is simply a role with `login` permission. It's more of a conceptual distinction. Technically a user and role are pretty much the same as far as I know.