# Rails: fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad) from Ruby, but ok in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, pg-hba.conf

I'm having problems assessing a postgres database from straight ruby.

I've created a Postgres database using Rails

```
>rails new www --database=postgresql
```

using Rails 4.2.5 and Postgres is 9.4

It produces the following **config/database.yml** file.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: www_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: www_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: www_production
  username: www
  password: <%= ENV['WWW_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I can run rails server, db:drop, db:create and db:migrate fine.

I can also access the database fine with psql

```
>psql www_development
```

**But** when I run the following **app.rb** from a non Rails project directory, I get a ***fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)*** error message.

It's clearly not a Rails issue. I've either missed something in my ruby or Postgres need a tweek to handle some difference between Rails and pure Ruby [that I'm not aware off]. I've also included Postgres' **pg_hba.conf** file.

At wits end trying to figure this one out. Any help would be much appreciated.

**app.rb**

```
require 'yaml'
require 'active_record'
require 'pg'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'postgresql',
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'www_development',
)
```

**/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Check this answer to properly create a postgresql user and add the user and password to the `database.yml` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23127354/2774342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify neither username, no password in your `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(`. I assume you want to use some `SUPERUSER` without password for `www_development` database - right?

as per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) **peer** auth does

> Obtain the client's operating system user name from the operating
>   system and check if it matches the requested database user name.

That is why if you can `psql` without password, you should be able run `app.rb` **with same OS user and environment** without password. If you can't, then `app.rb` tries to connect with different username or so...

Options:

1. put `username: postgres` to `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(`
2. change `local all all peer` to `local all all trust`

Comment: Thanks Tsun. I running app.rb, rails server and psql under that same user. I want to understand why I'm getting a different result in pure ruby. Are you saying rails server accesses the database as postgres, rather than the user that ran the command?

Comment: Could be. Try option 1. If it fixes the issue - yes

Comment: Well, using postgres as the user worked, so seems likely. I'm not leaving that info smeared over any code bases. I'm going with option 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure, @gnoll110

Answer (score 1):

With ENV variable as password it's very likely that the variable itself is not present. Confirm the presence with `printenv`. You need to relogin/reboot for the variable to be accessible after you've included it in `/etc/environment` file for example. If this works, it's probably better than changing `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: You can always source the file (`. /etc/environment`) and export the variable to make sure it's available to the function you start afterward. No need to log out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  # must specify the right DB, superuser and superuser Password as per postgreSQL setup
```

This worked for me, the only changes I needed to make. (ok fine i re-installed pgsql with 12.1)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when setting up a Rails 6 application.

The issue was that when start the rails server using `rails server`, and try to view the application from a browser, I get the error below:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was caused by me **not** specifying/supplying the database password to be used by the application, so when the application tries to connect to the database specified in the `config/database.yml` it runs into that error.

I solved it by specifying the database password for the application in the `config/database.yml`:

```
# The password associated with the postgres role (username).
password: my-password
```

Also, ensure that you've created the database for the application if you've not created it already using:

```
rails db:create
```

Afterwhich I restarted the rails server:

```
rails server
```

This time when I tried viewing the application from the browser, it worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use peer authentication which shouldn't ask for the password.

For me the issue was that I was specifying localhost in the database.yml so that was forcing the database driver to try to make a different type of connection (e.g., tcp, named pipe, etc)

Removing the "host: 'localhost'" line from my config solved the problem for me per this other answer: [ActiveRecord connection to a localhost postgresql database in trust mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987034/activerecord-connection-to-a-localhost-postgresql-database-in-trust-mode)

Note that in my case I'm using the 'peer' method and not the 'trust' method but the solution is the same