# ActiveRecord connection to a localhost postgresql database in trust mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, trust

If I try to connect with ActiveRecord to a localhost postgresql database with the following connection parameters :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'postgresql',
  username: 'test',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: '123456'
)
```

I get

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test" (PG::Error)
```

And with :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'postgresql',
  username: 'test',
  host: 'localhost'
)
```

I get

```
  fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

My pg_hba.conf lines are :

```
local   all             all                                     trust
local   all             postgres                                peer

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Why is ActiveRecord is not using the trust method. I set it for all database and all users (first line).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the `host: 'localhost'` line.

If this line is present in the connections parameters, then the driver try to make a localhost network connection rather than a sock connection.

So the **host** lines of the pg_hba.conf file are used rather than the **local** lines. And then the connection rightly ask you for a password.

If you remove this line and connect with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'postgresql',
  username: 'test'
)
```

Then you should be fine and be able to connect to your local database in trust mode.